YouTube Video Description Not Updating in Google Search Results After Editing: How to Resolve?
I've noticed a recurring issue with YouTube videos where, after initially posting a video and having it appear in Google search results, subsequent edits to the video description do not seem to be reflected in Google's search results. It appears that the initial description used during video posting carries significant weight, and edits made afterward do not get crawled or indexed by Google easily, if at all. This poses a challenge for content creators who may need to update or refine their video descriptions over time. Has anyone encountered this issue and found a successful approach to ensure that updated video descriptions are reflected in Google search results? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

How long does it take before it updates? Have you verified it isn't a caching issue by accessing the site from a different device on a different network that hasn't already accessed the content?

This issue with YouTube video descriptions not updating in Google search results is not uncommon, and it can be frustrating for content creators. Here are some insights and potential solutions that may help you address this problem:
Google's Crawling Frequency: Google does not crawl and index YouTube descriptions as frequently as other web content. It prioritizes the initial metadata (title, description, tags) provided when the video is first published. Subsequent edits may take a long time to be re-indexed, if they are at all.
Force Re-crawling: While there is no guaranteed way to force Google to re-crawl a YouTube video, there are a few strategies you can try:
Update Video Metadata: Along with updating the description, try updating other metadata such as the title, tags, and even the thumbnail. This can sometimes prompt Google to re-crawl the video.
Engage with the Video: Increase the video's activity by driving more traffic to it, generating comments, likes, and shares. Higher engagement can sometimes trigger a re-crawl.
Embed the Video on Your Website: If you have a website or blog, embed the video and write a blog post or article about it. Ensure the updated description is included in the post. Submit the URL of the blog post to Google Search Console to prompt a crawl.
YouTube Analytics: Monitor your YouTube analytics to see if the updated description is driving traffic through YouTube's own search algorithm. Even if Google Search does not update immediately, YouTube's internal search might reflect the changes more quickly.
Utilize Social Media: Share your updated video description on social media platforms and link back to your video. Increased social signals can sometimes influence Google's crawling behavior.
Patience and Consistency: Sometimes, the only solution is to be patient. Continue to update and optimize your video descriptions, and over time, Google may eventually re-crawl and index the new information.
Contact YouTube Support: If the issue persists and is significantly affecting your content, consider reaching out to YouTube support for assistance. They might provide specific insights or solutions tailored to your case.
By employing these strategies, you might increase the likelihood of having your updated video descriptions reflected in Google's search results. However, it's important to note that there are no guarantees, as Google's crawling and indexing processes can be unpredictable.

Please update this answer after reviewing How to reference material written by others as well as Web Apps SE policy on content generated by AI

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
